How to efficiently perform dynamic programming with complex state dependencies in Python?
I am working on a Python project that involves implementing a dynamic programming (DP) algorithm, but the state dependencies are not straightforward. Here's a simplified version of my problem:
I need to calculate the minimum cost to traverse a 2D grid where each cell has a cost, but the movement rules are unusual:
You can move down, right, or diagonally down-right.
Moving diagonally has an extra penalty depending on the sum of the costs of the starting and ending cells.
Additionally, the cost to move into a cell may depend on whether the previous move was horizontal, vertical, or diagonal.
For example:
If grid[i][j] is the cost of cell (i, j), then the cost to reach (i, j) from (i-1, j-1) (diagonal) would be:
dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1] + grid[i][j] + penalty_function(grid[i-1][j-1], grid[i][j])

But from (i-1, j) (vertical), it would simply be:
dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j] + grid[i][j]

I attempted the following approach:
def min_cost(grid):
    rows, cols = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    dp = [[float('inf')] * cols for _ in range(rows)]
    dp[0][0] = grid[0][0]  # Starting point

    for i in range(1, rows):
        for j in range(1, cols):
            vertical = dp[i-1][j] + grid[i][j]
            horizontal = dp[i][j-1] + grid[i][j]
            diagonal = dp[i-1][j-1] + grid[i][j] + penalty_function(grid[i-1][j-1], grid[i][j])
            dp[i][j] = min(vertical, horizontal, diagonal)

    return dp[-1][-1]

However, this becomes inefficient for larger grids because the penalty function itself can be computationally expensive, and the solution doesn't scale well when the grid size exceeds 1000x1000.
Is there a way to optimize this DP approach, possibly by memoizing or precomputing parts of the penalty function?
Would switching to libraries like NumPy or using parallel processing help in this scenario?
Are there Python-specific tricks (e.g., @functools.lru_cache, generators) that I could use to improve performance while keeping the code clean and readable?

We need to see the code of the penalty_function to help.

Pure-Python code is very slow because it manipulates dynamically-allocated reference-counted objects and the default CPython implementation is a slow interpreter which optimize nearly nothing. Lists of lists are slow because you need two fetch of dynamic objects, type checking, dynamic function calls etc. Please don't du such computation in CPython (except maybe for small data or prototyping).

Vectorizing this code with Numpy is complicated but you can use Numpy+Cython (with views) or Numpy+Numba. The resulting compiled/JITed code should be at least 10 times faster (probably much more in practice like 100 times). Not to mention the computation can be parallelized (not easy though, unless you write a native C/C++ module using OpenMP). All of this assume penalty_function can be JITed/compiled too (otherwise the function call overhead will be the main bottleneck anyway).

@JérômeRichard Writing pypy code looks just like using a restricted subset of Python, and is plenty fast.

@btilly PyPy help a lot because it is a JIT as opposed to CPython. But it is not as good as Numba mainly because PyPy is less restricted. If you are not convainced, try to write a matrix multiplication code with PyPy and lists. I did it. PyPy does not really vectorize the code (ie. use SIMD instruction) mainly because this is expensive (and PyPy is a tracing JIT, not a method JIT) and also because of a lot of guards (use to check types and non usual things). Because of that the optimized PyPy code was an order of magnitude slower than optimized native code (including Numba as fast as C)

@btilly Not to mention efficient parallelism in PyPy is still an issue and pretty complicated (meanwhile this is rather simple IMHO with OpenMP and even in Cython or Numba). On top of that, Lists of List are basically arrays containing pointers on arrays containing pointers on objects and PyPy cannot really optimize that (2 indirection per access -- possibly just 1 with caching and an additional data-dependent condition -- and no possible SIMD instructions).

@JérômeRichard You appear to be missing the fact that optimization is a tradeoff, and not an unlimited good. For most programmers, most of the time, Python is plenty fast. Where it's not, PyPy will be sufficiently fast instead. From there you can make a variety of more complex tradeoffs. I know the general theory from there, but only twice have I needed to go to C++ for a fundamentally faster approach. I've never personally needed to deal with OpenMP. But everyone's mileage varies on this.

@btilly My main point was to use Numpy+Cython or Numpy+Numba, not C++. To use Numba you only need 1 line : @numba.njit (same for penalty_function). As for Numpy, this is pretty trivial here too (eg. grid[i,j] rather than grid[i][j], and dp = np.full((row,col), np.infty) instead of dp = [[float('inf')] * cols for _ in range(rows)]). The Numpy+Numba code is as simple as the current one and orders of magnitude faster. As for PyPy, this is not a silverbullet : several modules are still not supported and using Numpy with PyPy is a mess IMHO. I like PyPy but it is not designed for that.

@JérômeRichard You're ignoring my point. My point is that most people don't care about optimal optimization advice, because most people won't need their code well-optimized. Ever. You're therefore trying to solve a problem that mostly doesn't exist.

@btilly The thing is we just don't know what the OP needs because we do not have any timings for the current code nor any timing target: this is missing in the question (as well as the cost/implem of penalty_function). While I agree that most people do not need optimal codes, the level of optimization depend of the targeted users. I personally worked a lot in the HPC field (and gaming industry) requiring pretty optimized codes while being still readable and maintainable for physicists (or biologists) which are not skilled programmers and prefer using Python.

@JérômeRichard In theory, yes. In practice, I've never seen someone ask an algorithm question here in Python, who needed better than the right algorithm with PyPy.

@btilly Following the performance tag, it is not rare to see questions where Numpy vectorization (or even Numba/BLAS) is not enough, so is PyPy. Here are some example : 1, 2, 2, 4. Sometimes using PyPy is a good idea but not enough alone.

@btilly But the biggest problem with PyPy is not much its performance but its compatibility and side effects on a whole application. Often, people cannot/don't-want-to replace CPython by PyPy globally due to that. PyPy cannot be applied on 1 or few functions. It does not support well modules like Numpy/Pandas (I tried several times few years ago and it was a mess). I used to be a PyPy power-user, but not anymore mainly due to that. Large (scientific) applications import a lot of modules (including Numpy-based ones) and the GC can be a problem too

I'm willing to believe that of the performance tag. But it doesn't invalidate what I said for the algorithm tag, which is how I got here.

DP can proceed in two ways.
The first is bottom up. That's harder but often more efficient on memory.
The second is top down. Just write a recursive function, then memoize it.
If you're struggling with bottom up, just try top down.
In your case, though, this will on a 1000x1000 grid require a million data values, which you access in strange patterns. Bottom up makes more sense. Instead of the previous suggestion of rows, I would suggest diagonals. At the worst point it is the same as rows. But usually it is smaller, improving cache usage.

You don't need to store the whole 2D array of dp values. Your algorithm only needs the current and previous rows. The computational complexity isn't changed by using only 2 rows, but the space complexity is so in practice, less memory requirement will probably give a performance boost.
